# Correct shutdown of ActiveMQ embedded broker

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I have a simple Spring config for unit tests that includes ActiveMQ embedded broker, JMS producer and JMS listener. Tests are passed successfully, but when shutting everything down I see some exceptions. Like this:

```
[ WARN] [ActiveMQ Connection Executor: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616 03:16:23] (SingleConnectionFactory.java:onException:301) Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
```

My configuration:

```
<beans>
  <amq:queue id="defaultDestination" physicalName="example.A"/>
  <bean id="jmsProducerTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="defaultDestination"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsMessageSender" class="package.JMSMessageSender"/>

  <amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false" destroyApplicationContextOnStop="true" >
    <amq:transportConnectors>
      <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>
  </amq:broker>

  <bean id="messageListener" class="package.MessageReceiver"/>

  <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" depends-on="broker">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
      <amq:connectionFactory brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" container-type="default">
    <jms:listener destination="example.A" ref="messageListener"/>
  </jms:listener-container>
</beans>
```

I supposed that broker is closing and then connection factory loses connection. But `depends-on` has not helped.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad far as I can tell, there is no way to shut down the embedded AMQ without these exceptions. The AMQ code treats that EOF as a relatively harmless event, but it does log that exception. You could try opening a JIRA at the Apache ActiveMQ project.